# 'Now stands' or 'now stand'

Tags: grammatical-number, british-english

Should it be...
"To the south now stand a car park and a cruise ship terminal"

OR

"To the sound now stands a car park and a cruise ship terminal"

Comment: Why not just use the usual order of words? There is now an x and y on the southside [of something]. Starting sentences with a prepositional phrase requires a basic knowledge of grammar first.

Comment: Why is this tagged "British English"?

Comment: The leading locative prepositional phrase invites inversion, but you’re right that it does not demand it. *To the south a car-park and a cruise-ship terminal now stand* is certainly fine, although the *now* only makes sense if contrasting wtih some previous time in which they did not.

Answer (score 2):

If the car park and the cruise ship terminal have nothing to do with one another,
then the NP *a car park and a cruise ship terminal* is plural, and *stand* is correct.

However, if they are being treated by the speaker as a single unit,
then that NP can be considered singular, and *stands* is correct.

The choice is the speaker's; but of course the addressee(s) may not always
make the same inferences and presuppositions that the speaker does.
This is a problem, but hardly a novel one.

Comment: If they were being treated as one, wouldn't it be: *a car park and cruise ship terminal*?

Comment: Maybe. Articles depend on prior context and speaker intention. Definite, indefinite, or zero articles can work, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Since "a car park and a cruise ship terminal" are the subject of the sentence, and are **plural**, the correct spelling would be **'stand'**:

> *To the south now stand a car park and a cruise ship terminal*.

Compare this to, for example, "*to your right stand the two main buildings*".

You can also use 'are standing', which might sound less strange.

<sup>(Notwithstanding the question of whether or not a car park can actually *stand*..)</sup>

Comment: Sure. + 1 I would imagine they now stand where once there was, for instance, an empty lot. I frankly don't have the patience. :)